# Tags inside value of appsettings of web.config. How?

Tags: .net, xml, web-config

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="CodeNF" value="somevalue"/>
  </appSettings>

In the above code, i need to put value="<somevalue>".
```

Is it possible to do that in my web.comfig ? Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to html encode the < and > characters

```
"&lt;somevalue&gt;"
```

Comment: +1 Exactly; smething like  `<add key="CodeNF" value="&lt;somevalue&gt;"/>